# Every locally presentable $\infty$-category can be presented by a proper model category

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, model-categories

Is there an argument in the litterature that show that every locally presentable $\infty$-category is equivalent to the localization of *proper* combinatorial Quillen model category ?

Of course if one removes *proper* this is well known, so equivalently I'm asking for a proof that every combinatorial model category equivalent to a proper one.

If one justs asks for right proper this is covered by Nikolaus construction (see corollary 2.21 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1342.pdf)). For left proper this can be achieved using the "dual" version of this construction by [Ching and Riehl](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5303) (at least in the simplicial case).

Another way to get a left proper model is through the general construction of a model category from a locally presentable $\infty$-category:

If $\mathcal{E}$ is a locally presentable $\infty$-category, then it is an accessible localization of a presheaf category $Prsh(D)$. One then takes a model of $D$ as a (cofibrant) simplicial category and build a model for $C$ as a left Bousfield localization of the injective model category of simplicial presheaves on $D$. As a localization of a proper model category, it will be left proper.

Unfortunately, these are in general not right proper (this is related to whether $\mathcal{E}$ is cartesian closed).

I think it is actually possible to build a proper model as follows: The previous construction gives a model category which is left proper and where every cofibration is a monomorphism, it seems that in this case, a careful analysis of the construction in Nikolaus [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1342.pdf), show that the resulting model structure is actually left proper (and it is right proper as mentioned above). However this observation requires a significant amount of work.

So:

- Is there a published reference that would allow to justify the left properness of Nikolaus construction in this case ?
- Is there another (maybe simpler) way to get proper models (preferably in the literature)?

Comment: It seems to me that the forgetful functor $U$, from algebraically-fibrant objects to the original category, should preserve pushouts? (maybe I am making a mistake here though). Granted this, since the weak equivalences are preserved and reflected by $U$, it becomes straightforward to deduce that if the original model category is left-proper, then the model category of algebraically-fibrant objects is also left proper.

Comment: @TimCampion it doesn't preserves pushout: the pushout taken in the original category has no reason to be fibrant - let alone be universal as an algebraicly fibrant object. Though in the nice situation where cofibrations are mono there is a nice description of pushout of cofibrations in algebraically fibrant object which only involves pushout of cofibration in the base category (a lot of them) which is why I think left properness is preserved. But the argument is involved enough that I'm hoping something simpler might be available...